# Does jbehave have a way to share variables between keywords?

Tags: java, testing, jbehave, jbehave-plugin, jbehave-maven-plugin

I have story something like this:

```
Scenario: Go to screen Configuration->Setup->Device Operation Mode , Set Device mode to IP if not matched
Given I am on page Configuration->Setup->Device Operation Mode
When I choose "IP" if not matched from "Operation Mode" dropdown
```

So *" When I choose "IP" if not matched..."* keyword is clicking on button and change my mode to IP.

My question is: if I want in the end of the test to add Scenario that returns the origin Device mode if it has changed.

Something like:

```
Scenario: Go to screen Configuration->Setup->Device Operation Mode , return device to origin mode
Given I am on page Configuration->Setup->Device Operation Mode
Then I  return device operation mode to origin mode
```

How can I know what the origin mode was?

Does jbehave have a way to share variables between keywords?